# What is wrong with my java code, it won't compile?

Tags: java, class, public

Okay so I typed a java code to do a simple function. Every time I enter it won't let me compile. Where is my error in this code?

```
public int add(int a, int b) {
 int sum;
 sum = a + b;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
 int x = 5;
 double y = 7; 
 int total = add(x,y);
 System.out.println(total);
}
```

Comment: "it won't let me compile" usually error message explains the problem. Could you post it?

Comment: `int sum;  sum = a + b;` -> `return a + b;`

Answer (score 2):

Multiple compiler errors:

- The `add` method is declared to return an `int`, but it has no `return` statement
- The `main` method is `static`, it cannot call the non-static method `add`
- The 2nd argument of `add` must be `int`, but in the call you're passing a `double`

Possible fixes:

```
public static int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int x = 5;
    int y = 7;
    int total = add(x, y);
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've written the add method to take two integer arguments, but have passed it an integer and a double.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is because your method is not "static"

Answer (score 0):

Your method `add` must **return** an `int`, and to call it without an instance it should be `static`. Like,

```
public static int add(int a, int b) {
    int sum;
    sum = a + b;
    return sum;
}
```

**or**

```
public static int add(int a, int b) {
    int sum = a + b;
    return sum;
}
```

**or**

```
public static int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

**or** create a `new` instance of the class and call `add` on it (after fixing the `return` issue).

Answer (score 0):

At first you hae to make some class. Class could be noun, one thing from the real life. For example `Sum` or a `Number`
Like this:

```
public class Sum {
    public int add(int a,int b) {
        return a+b;
    }

    public Sum() {
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Sum sum = new Sum();
        System.out.println(sum.add(6, 9));

    }

}
```

I think you should learn more about Object Oriented Programming.